# How to prevent dropping event when it is a broadcast stream?

Tags: stream, flutter, broadcast

I want to prevent flutter from dropping broadcast stream event when no widget is listening. Because I want to listen to this in other page routes.

I have bloc object like below.

```
class UserBloc extends Object {
    final _user = StreamController<UserModel>.broadcast();
    final _uid = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

    Stream<UserModel> get user => _user.stream;
    Stream<String> get uid => _uid.stream;

    Function(UserModel) get setUser => _user.sink.add;
    Function(String) get setUID => _uid.sink.add;
```

I am listening to those streams in my sub page route

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: userBloc.user,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.connectionState);
    print(snapshot.data);
    return Text('hi');
    },
),
```

It works without using broadcast stream. However, no luck when I changed to broadcast.

The problem is broadcast streams drop events when no one is listening but I want to start listening when my other MaterialPage pops up.

Using broadcast stream, data is always null in stream when I started listening.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `StreamController.broadcast` doesn't allow this. But you can use a `StreamController()` for `_uid` and expose `uid => _uid.stream.transform(LazyBroadcastTransformer())` where the transformer is coming from here:  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lazy_broadcast to

Answer (score 5):

Replace the StreamController by BehaviorSubject from [RxDart package](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart).

> A special StreamController that captures the latest item that has been
>   added to the controller, and emits that as the first item to any new
>   listener.